# How can char[] represent a UTF-8 string?

Tags: c, string, utf-8, c11

In C11, a new string literal was added with the prefix `u8`. This represents an array of chars with the text encoded as UTF-8. How is this even possible? Isn't a normal char signed? Meaning it has one bit less of information to use because of the sign bit? My logic would depict that a string of UTF-8 text would need to be an array of unsigned chars.

Comment: UTF-8 represents characters using more than 8 bits (which always confuses me as UTF-16 is 16bit). Also, a char is just a group of bits, so perhaps being signed or not only matters if you are thinking about the value as being a number. If you are thinking of it as being (part of) a representation of a utf-8 symbol, whether the compiler thinks that area in memory represents a signed or unsigned number doesn't matter. (This isn't an answer, just how my logic interprets this.)

Comment: @Oliver What is the part that confuses you? UTFf-8 is as much 8 bit as UTF-16 is 16 bit.

Comment: @MrLister UTF-16 characters take up either 1 or 2 bytes of memory. UTF-8 characters can take up any number of byes of memory (usually from 1-6 bytes). So to my mind, 'UTF-8' would be an 8 bit, ascii-like encoding. While the real UTF-8 would be better named UTF-48, or similar. Or at least, I think this is how it works. I never really understood variable width character encodings when I was doing C a couple of years ago, and now I work in happier languages where this isn't really a concern...

Comment: @Oliver: no, UTF-16 characters take up either 1 or 2 16-bit units, so that's either 2 or 4 bytes on a typical C implementation. The *n* in UTF-n stands for the size of the "code unit", not the size of a character in bits. This holds for UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32. All of those except UTF-32 use a variable number of code units per Unicode code point.

Comment: @Oliver what he said. And UTF-8 is max 32 bits, not 48.

Comment: I think it's a very good question, since the C standard otherwise uses only `unsigned char` for byte representations of objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't a normal char signed?

It's implementation-dependent whether `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`.

Further, the sign bit isn't "lost", it can still be used to represent information, and `char` is not necessarily 8 bits large (it might be larger on some platforms).

Comment: *"it may also be unsigned"* ... but not at the same time :-)

Comment: The standard says `char` is always 1 byte long. However, the size of a byte may vary. Use `CHAR_BIT` (from `limits.h`) to know the actual size of 1 byte.

Answer (score 7):

There is a potential problem here:

*If* an implementation with `CHAR_BIT == 8` uses sign-magnitude representation for `char` (so `char` is signed), then when UTF-8 requires the bit-pattern `10000000`, that's a negative 0. So *if* the implementation further does not support negative 0, then a given UTF-8 string might contain an invalid (trap) value of `char`, which is problematic. Even if it does support negative zero, the fact that bit pattern `10000000` compares equal as a `char` to bit pattern `00000000` (the nul terminator) is liable to cause problems when using UTF-8 data in a `char[]`.

I think this means that for sign-magnitude C11 implementations, `char` needs to be unsigned. Normally it's up to the implementation whether `char` is signed or unsigned, but of course if `char` being signed results in failing to implement UTF-8 literals correctly then the implementer just has to pick unsigned. As an aside, this has been the case for non-2's complement implementations of C++ all along, since C++ allows `char` as well as `unsigned char` to be used to access object representations. C only allows `unsigned char`.

In 2's complement and 1s' complement, the bit patterns required for UTF-8 data are valid values of `signed char`, so the implementation is free to make `char` either signed or unsigned and still be able to represent UTF-8 strings in `char[]`. That's because all 256 bit patterns are valid 2's complement values, and UTF-8 happens not to use the byte `11111111` (1s' complement negative zero).

Comment: Your post uses a wrong premise, namely that implementations would be silly enough to allow for -0 values for chars. They never are.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I don't think my answer makes any supposition at all about what implementations actually do. It merely enumerates what they're (not) allowed to do, and in particular the one representation newly ruled out by the requirement in C11 to support UTF-8. For all practical purposes, every implementation is 2's complement, but the standard continues to permit the (silly) alternatives.

Comment: I think your post is very insightful, but here's where I am confused: The C++11 standard allows an `unsigned char` and `char` to be used for aliasing (see §3.10/15) and C11 even allows *all* character types (see §6.5/7). To me, this means that these types must be capable of reading a byte of value `11111111` (or *any* other byte value). In C++11, this can be resolved by making a plain `char` unsigned *if* 2's complement isn't used. But in C11 this can't ever be resolved if 2's complement *isn't* used, because aliasing must work with all character types (§6.5/7), that is, even an explicitly ...

Comment: declared signed char. This means, C11 implicitly mandates 2's complement (so that there are no trap values) while at the same time allowing 1's complement and sign-magnitude in §6.2.6.2/2. I think this is a bug in the standard. What do you think? My opinion is that both C++ and C should mandate 2's complement and stop this "we are going to support everything no matter the cost till the end of time" mess that is seriously confusing for someone who wants to write standard-compliant code.  If there's still a meaningful CPU in use out there that doesn't use 2's complement, one can easily use a ...

Comment: ... compiler flag selecting an older C or C++ standard which allows that.

Comment: @JohnCaC2: I don't have the standards to hand, but I think if all character types are permitted for aliasing that *doesn't* mean you have to use 2's complement. It just means you have to support negative zero for char types if you don't use 2's complement. That avoids there being trap values, although there are bitwise-different values that compare equal. The latter, although it would be an implementation failure in handling UTF-8 data using sign-magnitude as I describe in the answer, is not an implementation failure for aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

No, a sign bit is a bit nonetheless! And the UTF-8 specification itself doesn't say that the chars must be unsigned.

PS Wat is kookwekker voor 'n naam?

Answer (score 1):

The signedness of char does not matter; utf8 can be handled with only shift and mask operations (which may be cumbersome for signed types, but not impossible) But: utf8 *needs* at least 8 bits, so "assert (CHAR_BIT >= 8);"

To illustrate by point: the following fragments contains no arithmetic operations on the character's value, only shift&mask.

```
static int eat_utf8(unsigned char *str, unsigned len, unsigned *target)
{
unsigned val = 0;
unsigned todo;

if (!len) return 0;

val = str[0];
if ((val & 0x80) == 0x00) { if (target) *target = val; return 1; }
else if ((val & 0xe0) == 0xc0) { val &= 0x1f; todo = 1; }
else if ((val & 0xf0) == 0xe0) { val &= 0x0f; todo = 2; }
else if ((val & 0xf8) == 0xf0) { val &= 0x07; todo = 3; }
else if ((val & 0xfc) == 0xf8) { val &= 0x03; todo = 4; }
else if ((val & 0xfe) == 0xfc) { val &= 0x01; todo = 5; }
else {  /* Default (Not in the spec) */
        if (target) *target = val;
        return -1; }


len--;str++;
if (todo > len) { return -todo; }

for(len=todo;todo--;) {
        /* For validity checking we should also
        ** test if ((*str & 0xc0) == 0x80) here */
        val <<= 6;
        val |= *str++ & 0x3f;
        }

if (target) *target = val;
return  1+ len;
}
```

Comment: Note that the Standard _guarantees_ `CHAR_BIT` ≥ 8.